# ¿Cómo puedo, dependiendo del signo (+, -, *, /) se puede ejecutar el programa: ej .: ./hello 2 + 2

Tags: c, operador, switch

como hago dependiendo de los signos de matemáticas se pueda ejecutar el programa , utilizo el switch para que dependiendo casos el usuario solo poniendo ex: 2+2 el programa diga heyyy puso un + eso es el 2º caso entonces ejecuta el codigo despues pero me detecta switch mi string ....entonces si lo convierto a int ....mal , long....no .....entonces no se que hacer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hi, Cristian. You're in stackoverflow en español. Please, edit your question, translate it and add your code without images 'cause it could be closed. Regards.

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.
Lo otro: ¿C# o C? No es lo mismo en lo absoluto. Por favor, edita la pregunta y revisa cuál es la etiqueta correcta.

Comment: disculpame ya lo cambie :)

Comment: El código de las imágenes no puede copiarse... lo que imposibilita que lo probemos. Además, si la imagen deja de estar disponible en el futuro la pregunta no ayudará a nadie. Las imágenes deben ser complementos de la pregunta, no parte esencial de la misma

Comment: o listo entendi si quiero colocar el codigo seria ex : ` #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])   //Enter data before running a program
{
    if (argc <= 3)  //I could not pass 3 data
 {
    printf("error se ha introducido 2 o mas argumentos solo es el archivo y nombre\n");  //If it passes 3 data, print error and return 1
    return 1;
 }


    string palabra = argv[1];


} `   verdad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema que tiene es que en switch se evalúa la variable que seleccionas y en los case se pone el valor de esa variable. No puedes poner case sig = +
Debes poner directamente:

```
switch (sig)
{
  case '+':
    //lo que quieras que pase con +
    break;  //si olvidas el break se van a realizar todos los cases de ahi en adelante
  case '-':
    //lo que quieras en -
    break;
  default:
    //si no ingresa en ninguna opcion cual es el codigo por defecto. Puedes no ponerlo. y no lleva break al final
}
```

El símbolo de + y - tiene que evaluarlo como texto. Por eso las comillas simples.

Comment: hola bro..... gracias la verdad lo pude resolver y si tienes razon + y - debe ser caracteres y donde esta switch(sig[0]) para que sepa que la "primera" letra es lo que define los casos gracias